# null pointer exception on shared preferences

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I've a method in my activity , How do I call that method from another class (Not from activity) , since I need to pass arguments to that class . Am getting nullPointerException if I create an object for my activity , please anyone help me

Comment: If you need to back your activity from another class then send a reference of the activity while calling method of the class and you can back by the reference you used.No need to create Activity object

Answer (score 0):

Dont put your data in Activity class . Generally from activy to activity Bundle params is used to pass data . BUt if you tell me your exact problem then may be taht we can find any solution.

Comment: am getting the activity object as well , but when am trying for someContext.getSharedPreferences("key",0) its returning null .

Comment: Can you exactly tell what it si returning as null sharedpreference object as null or value returned as null . If value is returned as null then it means that the value is not saved and default null value is returned that default null value you can change .

Comment: Please also mention the exact scenerio .

Comment: sharedpreference object is not null , when i run this code someContext.getSharedPreferences("key",0) its returning null pointer exception

Comment: Please also mention the exact scenerio .I am not able to understand what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if i understood correctly but,

Can't you pass around a reference from the Activity to the "other" class method? Like :

```
class YourClass {
   //bla bla bla

  public void yourMethod(Activity activity) 
  {
    if(null != activity)
     activity.method();
    else
     //something
  }
}
```

cheers